# Why opening bootstrap modal using wire:click and dispatch event Blocks Scrolling in admin menu

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a problem when I use the following code for adding and displaying:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalYear">
    <span class="sub-item">Add year</span>
</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ListYear">
    <span class="sub-item">Listyear</span>
</a>
```

Nothing gets blocked but the problem comes when I want to use the edit option the admin menu stops scrolling, this is where the problem starts and also when I use this :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" wire:click="ShowReportModal('add')">
    span class="sub-item">Add Year</span>
</a>
```

the modal will show up but when I close it the admin menu stops scrolling.

After so many tries I figured out that the problem is using wire:click to call the modal for adding, editing and displaying.

this is my component:

```
 public function ShowReportModal($action)
{
    if($action == 'add')
    {
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('ModalYearVisible') ;
    }
    else{
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('ModalListVisible') ;
    }
}
```

Here is the admin menu code:

```
 <li class="nav-item">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#annee">
                        <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                        <p>Scholar year</p>
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
      <div class="collapse" id="annee">
                        <ul class="nav nav-collapse">
                            <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" wire:click="ShowReportModal('add')">
                <span class="sub-item">Add year</span>
                                </a>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" wire:click="ShowReportModal('list')">
                <span class="sub-item">Years List</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

Any help would be appreciated and also why is this happening?

Comment: How does your browser respond to the "ModalYearVisible" and "ModalListVisible" events?

Comment: What do you mean? It only shows the modals

Comment: What he means, is how are you listening to those events, what code do they run when the event is fired?

Comment: by using this  window.addEventListener('ModalYearVisible', event => {
            $('#modalYear').modal('show');
        });

Comment: could you post the blade code of the component? also check on console if any issue is showed

Comment: of course, no there are no errors in the console